# How can make this header to be on every page?

Tags: header-footer

I want the number 510000000 to be on every page on the top right corner what command do I use? Thank you in advance.

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%% Graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AddEverypageHook
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \hspace{\paperwidth}%
    \raisebox{-\baselineskip}{%
      \makebox[0pt][r]{510000000}
     }}}%

% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddEverypageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\atxy{0.1in}{0.1in}{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=0.53in]{logo.jpg}
}}
\begin{document}
%% Titlepage
\vspace*{.2in}
\lipsum[1]
\includepdf{Plagiarism.pdf}

\title{Lab Report}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `top right corner` is not pretty well-defined. Using `fancyhdr` this can be very easy

Comment: Could you possible tell me the code I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `fancyhdr`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\rhead{510000000}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I changed your document in 2 ways.  I replaced the `\includegraphics` in the `\atxy` argument #3 with  text, and I increased the value of the 1st argument to `\atxy` (to a value of `\dimexpr\paperwidth-.7in`) to shift the block to the right.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%% Graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddEverypageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\atxy{\dimexpr\paperwidth-1.5in}{0.1in}{\raisebox{-\height}{\Huge510000000}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this exactly what I wanted. I wish I could thank you in person but have a smiley face instead :)

Comment: @user2693902  You can always click the check mark to the left of my answer to indicate that of the answers, this one is accepted as best.  Also, on any answer given, you can click the up-arrow to the left of the answer if you feel the answer adds value to your understanding.